# Hibernate 4.1 - get() Function for any Object

Tags: hibernate, get

An example of getting data out of a database using Hibernate:

```
Cat cat = session.get( Cat.class, catId );
```

I'm asking myself, if it is possible to generate a static function (e.g. in HibernateUtil.java) that allows to get any Object from a session. Something like that:

```
public static Object getObjectfromDatabase(Class class, long id) {
    ...
    return session.get( class, id );
}
```

Of course "Class class" is no valid expression, but how can I identify an object in this situation?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "how can I identify an object in this situation" ?

Comment: i need something to get the class of an object. But if I use for example an Instance of Object but I have a Cat Object and i try to to find out the class (object.getClass() I always get Object as a result.

Comment: This doesn't seem much hibernate related to me. It seems to be a basic java question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While `Class class` is not valid, you can use `Class<?> class`. With this change the universal query method should work. If you don't know the class, get it from the entity itself:

```
MyEntity entity = (MyEntity) getObjectfromDatabase(MyEntity.class, entity.getId());
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Seems good to me, but i tried it and it did not work. I think the problem is, that (in your case) entity is null before and so getClass() dosen't work.

Comment: @MS1 ouch! definitely, thanks for noticing. Sincle you know the class of the entity where you call the function, you can also use the class object. I have edited the answer accordingly